# Fight between Shani and Sun(Surya)?

Tags: surya, shani

It is well known that Lord Shani is [son of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shani#Legends) Surya.

There is a [famous story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shani#Legends) that when Shani dev opened his eyes as a baby for the very first time, the sun went into an eclipse.

Here is one more interesting mentioning about **Shani and Surya** in [Shani Chalisa](http://www.voidcan.org/shani-chalisa/)

> रवि कहं मुख महं धरि तत्काला । लेकर कूदि परयो पाताला ॥

This loosely **[translates](http://www.answers.com/Q/Can_anyone_translate_the_shani_chalisa)** to :

> Swallowing the Sun(Surya), you(Shani) went to third world(पाताला )

Does this mean there was quarrel between Shani Dev and Surya dev?

What was the reason that Shani took Surya to third world(पाताला)?

Comment: These are symbolic stories used to enunciate astrological concepts. There is no inherent 'hatred' between the two planets. The story just shows that they inherently give opposite results in the astrological context. Sun brings glory, ego, royal positions etc. Saturn brings the opposite i.e. hardship, service, troubles with government etc. Specific results can only be predicted from the individual's chart.